# Rails: links in email to execute post action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

In emails, the only type of action possible is to send link (GET method).

What is the correct approach to send a link that will execute a POST action in the app (Eg. accept friendship)?

I see two possible solutions:

- custom GET action only used in the email (eg. `/action?type=accept_friendship&user_id=10`)
- get to a page and execute javascript on load to execute the action (eg. what Twitter does to follow back a user from an email)

How does those solutions compare? Are there others?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A link with a GET action is ok as long as you include a unique token in the url to confirm validity & origin of the action